# WPF hitTest на сам UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть у меня `UserControl` под именем `Pin`. Внутри него есть несколько элементов `Path`. При использовании `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` я получаю ссылки на эти `Path`, однако я хочу получать ссылку на сам `Pin`. Я узнал, что нужно использовать

```
protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
{
    return new PointHitTestResult(this, hitTestParameters.HitPoint);
}
```

внутри кода моего `Pin`, но я по прежнему получаю ссылки на `Path` вместо `Pin`.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А какую перегрузку `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` используете? По умолчанию возвращается самый верхний элемент, но можно фильтровать, смотрите пример кода здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.hittestfiltercallback(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `HitTestResult hitTest = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(MainWindow.main, mouse);`

Comment: Ну дык попробуйте другую перегрузку: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms608753(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ничего не понимаю. `HitTestResult hitTest = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(MainWindow.main, PinHitFilter, PinHitResult, new PointHitTestParameters(mouse));` выдает ошибку "Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "void" в System.Windows.Media.HitTestResult", хотя эти обработчики я по сути скопировал с https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms608753(v=vs.110).aspx и в них самих ошибок нет.

Comment: Ну этот метод не возвращает никакое значение. Обрабатывайте результат в resultCallback, смотрите пример внимательнее

Comment: Точно. Заработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В поиске:

```
void click()
{
    Pin pin = null;
    Vector2 mouse = Mouse.GetPosition(MainWindow.main).ToVector2();
    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(MainWindow.main, PinHitFilter, PinHitResult, new PointHitTestParameters(mouse));
}

HitTestFilterBehavior PinHitFilter(DependencyObject o)
{
    if (o is Pin) return HitTestFilterBehavior.ContinueSkipChildren;
    return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;
}

HitTestResultBehavior PinHitResult(HitTestResult result)
{
    Pin pin = result.VisualHit as Pin;
    return HitTestResultBehavior.Stop;
}
```

В элементе:

```
protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
{
    return new PointHitTestResult(this, hitTestParameters.HitPoint);
}
```

Так этот способ работает.